# why does tensorflow have multi versions released at the same time.? such as 2.5.1,2.4.3,2.3.4 release at the same time

Tags: tensorflow

I noticed each time,when tensorflow released,https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases
there are multi different version released at the same time,
what's the differences between the versions.

Answer (score 1):

Software, especially open source software usually has multiple releases at the same time ( Long Term Support, Stable, WHQL, etc...), as well as depending on the how many people use specific version, they might keep that version updated more ( either because breaking changes that the users can't update or other reasons )

Whenever there is a critical/security bugfix, if possible, all the branches will receive that bugfix..

This is what happened with TensorFlow, the latest release on 3 versions was all security/vulnerability bugfixes